# What is right part in "query : SelectionSet Response RootQuery" type annotations?

Tags: elm

I try to understand [this line](https://github.com/dillonkearns/elm-graphql/blob/02c59a90ba497d9e2e88aeb181bc941239b23214/examples/src/Example01BasicQuery.elm#L37):

```
query : SelectionSet Response RootQuery
```

I understand this is a ["Type Annotations"](https://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#type-annotations) syntax, but I don't find documentation example or explanation about multiple "word" separated by whitespace.

I see these examples:

- `answer : Int`
- `factorial : Int -> Int`
- `distance : { x : Float, y : Float } -> Float`
- `add : number -> number -> number` ([ref](https://elmprogramming.com/type-system.html#function-type))

I found anywhere `query: Int Int Int` syntax, neither in [Elm Syntax](https://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax) nor in [Beginning Elm](https://elmprogramming.com/type-system.html#function-type) nor in [Elm FAQ](https://faq.elm-community.org/).

Do `SelectionSet`, `Response`, `RootQuery` are

- functions arguments?
- multi value function results?

Best regards,
Stéphane

---

[Same question on Elm Discourse](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/what-is-right-part-in-query-selectionset-response-rootquery-type-annotations/7364)

---

A response in [How do I read the type of a SelectionSet?](https://github.com/dillonkearns/elm-graphql/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-read-the-type-of-a-selectionset)

Comment: It's a type with type variables. See the section on "Type Variables" in https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html

Answer (score 1):

[`SelectionSet`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/dillonkearns/elm-graphql/latest/Graphql-SelectionSet#SelectionSet) is a type with two type variables. Here's the definition:

```
type SelectionSet decodesTo scope
    = SelectionSet (List RawField) (Decoder decodesTo)
```

In a type declaration like this, any lowercase name after the type is a type variable, which can be filled in by any type (except for a few special [constrained type variables](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html#constrained-type-variables), `number`, `appendable`, `comparable`, and `compappend`). A simpler example would be [`Maybe`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe#Maybe), where you can have a `Maybe Int` or a `Maybe String`. Similarly, [`Dict`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#Dict) takes two type variables (for the key and value) so you can have `Dict String String` or `Dict Int MyCustomType` (the key type of a `Dict` does need to be `comparable`).

So, in your scenario, `Response` corresponds to `decodesTo` and `RootQuery` corresponds to `scope`. The `SelectionSet` has a `Decoder` that decodes to a `Response` value, and it also carries around this `scope` type variable, which isn't used directly in the data that it holds. It's used as a piece of information at the type level, so that you (and the library) know that calling [`map`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/dillonkearns/elm-graphql/latest/Graphql-SelectionSet#map) (which has the type `(a -> b) -> SelectionSet a scope -> SelectionSet b scope`) will preserve that `scope` value; that is, it prevents mixing scopes.

Answer (score -1):

The above is mostly general function syntax for functional languages such as Haskell, Elm, etc.

For example:

```
add : Int -> Int -> Int 
add x y = x + y
```

The first line says that is function of two integer arguments with an integer return value.   The second line implements the specification given in the first.  One calls this function as follows:

```
> add 2 3
  5
```

Note this example:

```
> inc = add 1
> inc 2
  3
```

Here `add 1` is a "partially applied function." It has type `Int -> Int`.  In many languages, `add 1` would not make sense.  But since functions are first-class things in Elm, `add 1` makes sense: it is a function.  Partial application is also called "currying."